# How do I split a stack of items?

Tags: torchlight

I recently discovered that if you put a town portal scroll in your pet's inventory the pet will return instantly from the trip. This is great, but so far I've only managed to give entire stacks of the scroll to my pet, who will then gladly sell all of it, leaving me with no scrolls in case of emergency. How do I split a stack of items?

Comment: PC version I presume? What keys have you tried? Shift click?

Comment: @JamesJiao On Windows, yes. I've tried all three modifier keys to no avail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't manually split a stack of items unfortunately.  The game will always try to stack all your items as you pick them up into a single stack if possible.  If what you're picking up will not fit in the current stack or you don't have any of that item, it will create a new stack.

You can "cheat" this a bit.  First find the item you want to put into a new stack.  Before picking it up, give the rest of what you have in the existing stack to your pet and *then* pick it up (or go the other way around and have your pet pick it up).  As long as you don't take it back from the pet or give up what you have, your stacks will be split.

You could also just drop the stack as well to achieve the same thing.  But once merged, you're stuck with that stack until you sell it or fill it up.

I know, it's a pain, but that just the way it is.

Comment: Just curious, is it "fixed" in Torchlight 2?

Comment: It is. There, you can split your stacks by holding control and clicking on the stack you want to split. A slider will pop up allowing you to choose how much you want to pick up from the stack.

Comment: Nice, like in many other games. Thanks, another reason to start playing then! ;)

Comment: Is there a mod to do this instead of the "cheat"?

Comment: @Propeller: Not that I know of. Frankly I just wouldn't worry about it. After being so far past the game's typical lifespan, it wouldn't surprise me if there still wasn't. Keeping separate stacks of an item wasn't too much of a problem, considering you typically had to sell an abnormally large quantity of items just to make a dent in earning gold. Though, I'm sure there are mods for making the price of stuff more reasonable.